# How to make vertical lines in the planes zx and z and gnuplot

Tags: grid, gnuplot, z-axis

I need a little help.
I'm making a three surfaces together in gnuplot, but I need to place the vertical and horizontal grids for the Z axis on the back of the surfaces. I've only been able to make the horizontal lines, and I want to add the vertical lines, some suggestions to do this in my code

Thank you very much.

```
set key outside
set rmargin at screen 0.6
set lmargin at screen 0.18
set title 'Gnuplot surfaces'
set key 
set pm3d depthorder hidden3d 1
set hidden3d offset 0
set xlabel "X"
set xrange [ -4.0000 : 4.0000 ] noreverse nowriteback
set mxtics 4
set ylabel 'Y'
set yrange [ -4.0000 : 4.0000 ] noreverse nowriteback
set mytics 4
set zlabel "Z" 
set zrange [-1.000: 1.000] noreverse nowriteback
set mztics 4
set surface
set isosamples 25
unset colorbox
set ticslevel 0
set grid ztics xtics ytics lt 2 lc rgb "black"
set border 4095
set view 43, 32
a(x,y)= sin(sqrt(x**2+y**2)) / sqrt(x**2+y**2)
b(x,y)= x**3*y**2
c(x,y)= sin(x) * cos(y)
splot a(x,y) lc rgb 'gray' linewidth 2, b(x,y) lc rgb 'red' linewidth 0.5, c(x,y) lc rgb 'blue' linewidth 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add a data block (gnuplot 5.0 or greater) for all the grid lines as vectors:

```
$data << EOD
-4 -3 -1 0 0 2
-4 -2 -1 0 0 2
-4 -1 -1 0 0 2
-4  0 -1 0 0 2
-4  1 -1 0 0 2
-4  2 -1 0 0 2
-4  3 -1 0 0 2
-3  4 -1 0 0 2
-2  4 -1 0 0 2
-1  4 -1 0 0 2
 0  4 -1 0 0 2
 1  4 -1 0 0 2
 2  4 -1 0 0 2
 3  4 -1 0 0 2
EOD
```

Now, just create an arrow style as black with no heads and add this 'file' to the plot with vectors and no title.

```
set style arrow 1 nohead lc 'black'
replot "$data" with vectors arrowstyle 1 title ""
```

If you do not have gnuplot 5.0 or greater, put the data block in a file and just plot the file.

Comment: although gnuplot, should set that requirement as your own command, and so you do not have to create an extra vector to show the lines